# Visual Studio 2019 Javascript XML Comments not showing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, comments, intellisense

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 Community Version 16.9.5.

I created a brand new ASP.net Web-App-Project for VB.net.

In that project i added a new javascript-file.

Now i write a javascript function with xml comments like:

```
function test(a) {
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a test
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">Test a</param>  
}
```

Prior to VS2019 i worked with VS2013.

In VS2013 when i type "test(" in VS2013 the XML-comments will show as expected like this

[XML comments showing in VS2013][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqBlN.jpg

In VS2019 i only get this

[XML comments NOT showing in VS2019][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOK5z.jpg

In a vb.net file in the same project the comments show, only in JS the don't show.

Do i have to kind of enable the XML comments for JS somewhere in the VS settings or have to install an addon?

Answer (score 0):

i also posted the question on Microsoft Q&A and got an answer there:

VS2019 uses a new notation for javascript xml-comments:

```
/** This is a test. */
 function test1(a) 
 {
    
 }

/** 
  *  This is a test. 
  *  @param {string} a - the parameter.
  */
 function test2(a) 
 {
    
 }
```